# Best approximation to an adjoint functor

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra, adjoint-functors

I have the following question.

Suppose I have a functor $F\colon C\to D$ between two categories. I would like it to have an  adjoint (say, right), but it doesn't. Is there a way to define a "best approximation" to its adjoint?

An obvious way is to define $G\colon D\to C$ be a functor with a natural transformation, say, $\alpha_G\colon Hom(F(-),-)\to Hom(-,G(-))$ such that $G$ is universal. I mean, such that for any other $H\colon D\to C$ and $\alpha_H\colon Hom(F(-),-)\to Hom(-,G(-))$, $\alpha_H$ will factor through $\alpha_G$.

I guess we can give similar definition with arrows $\alpha_H$ going in the opposit direction. The problem is I am not sure if such definition will be at all useful. It feels like the problem of finding "approximations to an adjoint functor" is similar to finding factorization of one functor through another (where the best solution is given by Kan extension). But I am not sure if there is a connection.

So the question is:

> Does it make sence to talk about best approximations to an adjoint functor? If yes, what is the correct definition? Have such approximations been studied? If yes, can you, please, give a reference? What if categories $F$ and $G$ have some extra-structure (say, are DG categories)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: A left adjoint for $G$ is precisely an absolute right Kan extension of $\mathrm{id}$ along $G$.

Comment: There is probably hope that your functor satisfies some weaker condition than admitting a right adjoint, but it probably depends on _why_ you want it to admit an adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

There is a construction along these lines, though I am not sure exactly what it is useful for. I will consider the best approximation to a *left* adjoint, to match the reference to the literature.

First, recall that a [relative left adjoint](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relative+adjoint+functor) to a functor $r \colon C \to E$ comprises a pair of a functor $j \colon A \to E$ and a functor $\ell \colon A \to C$ such that there is a natural isomorphism $C(\ell x, y) \cong E(j x, r y)$. When $j$ is fully faithful, this can be considered a notion of *partial left adjoint*.

For every functor $r \colon C \to E$, one can construct the universal partial left adjoint. This is given by defining $A$ to be the full subcategory of $E$ spanned by those objects $e \in E$ for which $E(e, r{-}) \colon C \to \mathbf{Set}$ is representable: the representation will be the assignment on objects of the functor $\ell$ (whose functoriality may then be uniquely determined).

This construction was originally described by Isbell under the name *pre-coadjoint* in [Structure of categories](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-04/S0002-9904-1966-11541-0/S0002-9904-1966-11541-0.pdf), and later described in terms of relative adjunctions by Ulmer in [Properties of dense and relative adjoint functors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869368900367) (footnote 10).

I don't believe the construction has been studied in much detail other than proving its existence. (Isbell proves some other properties, but these are actually more general properties of relative adjunctions.) The construction should work just as well for other notions of categories and relative adjunctions, such as enriched categories, though I don't believe there are references.